# Division in Mysql query

Tags: mysql, division

I have 2 different query which will return values : 1502.00 and 6

```
SELECT replace(CURRENT_VALUE,'$','') curVal
FROM form_attributes_values
WHERE TEST_ID=2
AND ATTRIBUTE_ID = (
    SELECT ATTRIBUTE_ID
    FROM form_attributes
    WHERE FORM_ID=6
    AND FORM_FIELD_NAME='REGRINDABLECUTTERCOST'
)
```

and

```
SELECT replace(CURRENT_VALUE,'$','') curVal
FROM form_attributes_values
WHERE TEST_ID=2
AND ATTRIBUTE_ID = (
    SELECT ATTRIBUTE_ID
    FROM form_attributes
    WHERE FORM_ID=6
    AND FORM_FIELD_NAME='REGRINDSPOSSIBLE'
)
```

I am trying to perform division query1/query2 (1502.00/6) which should return value `250.333333`

but the value i am getting is something like `0.16666666666666`

below are the types which is have tried so for:
Type 1:

```
select (a.curVal / b.curVal) as final_count
from (
    SELECT replace(CURRENT_VALUE,'$','') curVal
    FROM form_attributes_values
    WHERE TEST_ID=2 AND ATTRIBUTE_ID = (
        SELECT ATTRIBUTE_ID
        FROM form_attributes
        WHERE FORM_ID=6
        AND FORM_FIELD_NAME='REGRINDABLECUTTERCOST'
    )
) a,
(
    SELECT replace(CURRENT_VALUE,'$','') curVal
    FROM form_attributes_values
    WHERE TEST_ID=2
    AND ATTRIBUTE_ID = (
        SELECT ATTRIBUTE_ID
        FROM form_attributes
        WHERE FORM_ID=6
        AND FORM_FIELD_NAME='REGRINDSPOSSIBLE'
    )
) b;
```

Type 2:

```
SELECT replace(CURRENT_VALUE,'$','') / (
    SELECT replace(CURRENT_VALUE,'$','') curVal
    FROM form_attributes_values
    WHERE TEST_ID=2
    AND ATTRIBUTE_ID = (
        SELECT ATTRIBUTE_ID
        FROM form_attributes
        WHERE FORM_ID=6
        AND FORM_FIELD_NAME='REGRINDSPOSSIBLE'
    )
) curVal
FROM form_attributes_values
WHERE TEST_ID=2
AND ATTRIBUTE_ID = (
    SELECT ATTRIBUTE_ID
    FROM form_attributes
    WHERE FORM_ID=6
    AND FORM_FIELD_NAME='REGRINDABLECUTTERCOST'
)
```

both the type return `0.166666666666667` am i missing anything...?

Comment: Please post example schema for `form_attributes_values` and `form_attributes`, and just enough data to reproduce your query as it is. Faking your provided select results does not reproduce your problem, so the problem is very likely in your schema definition and/or actual queries.

Comment: **WHY** do you store your numeric values in strings??? I suspect that it is **the cause** of your downfall. You attempt to divide a string value by the number, string value is converted (not very successfully) to the number first

Comment: Thank you Germann Arlington, you are 100% correct, issue was due to the String field, the value in database was like "$1,500.00", hence the query was able to pick "1" instead of "1500.00"

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have problem with first query only, because **1** / **6** = **0.166666666666667**.

Answer (score 1):

OK so i just tried this in the SQL console on PHPmyAdmin and got the answer 250.3333

```
SELECT cast(1502.00 AS unsigned) / cast(6 AS unsigned);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select sum(a.curVal) / sum(b.curVal) as final_count from 
(SELECT replace(CURRENT_VALUE,'$','') curVal FROM form_attributes_values WHERE TEST_ID=2     AND ATTRIBUTE_ID = (SELECT ATTRIBUTE_ID FROM form_attributes WHERE FORM_ID=6     AND FORM_FIELD_NAME='REGRINDABLECUTTERCOST')) a,
(SELECT replace(CURRENT_VALUE,'$','') curVal FROM form_attributes_values WHERE TEST_ID=2 AND ATTRIBUTE_ID = (SELECT ATTRIBUTE_ID FROM form_attributes WHERE FORM_ID=6 AND FORM_FIELD_NAME='REGRINDSPOSSIBLE')) b;
```

It's not tested but you should have better luck with using SUM.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Both of the query type will work fine, problem was in the value, value stored in Database was of String type and also the value was coma separated (1,502.00) instead of (1502.00)