# How can I divide two different sums in SQL?

Tags: sql

I have three tables:

```
players(playerID: integer, firstName: string, lastName: string)  
gamestats(playerID: integer, gameID: integer, stat: string, result: double)  
games(playerID: integer, gameID: integer, gametype: string)
```

Givens:

1. There are two different strings in gamestats.stat: 'hits' & 'throws'
2. The gamestats.result column contains the respective accomplishment result.
3. The games.gametype column contains the gametype, ie. 'gameA', 'GameB', etc.

What I want is to return something along the lines of:

```
SELECT SUM('hits')/SUM('throws') AS GameA_HitsPerThrow
WHERE games.gametype = 'gameA'
AND games.playerID = 1;
```

I know this isn't valid SQL, but I hope the psuedocode makes sense.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm new to this.

**Edit:**

Sample data:

```
player(1, 'John', 'D')
player(2, 'Alice', 'H')
gamestats(1, 1708, hits, 4)
gamestats(1, 1708, throws, 4)
gamestats(2, 1708, hits, 8)
gamestats(2, 1708, throws, 7)
gamestats(1, 1709, hits, 9)
gamestats(1, 1709, throws, 13)
gamestats(2, 1709, hits, 6)
gamestats(2, 1709, throws, 10)
games(1, 1708, 'gameA')
games(2, 1708, 'gameA')
games(1, 1709, 'gameA')
games(2, 1709, 'gameA')
```

Here's what I have so far, but all it does is return all the rows from the query (although it also contains duplicates for some reason):

```
SELECT gamestats.stat, gamestats.result FROM `gamestats`
INNER JOIN games 
ON gamestats.gameID = games.gameID
WHERE game.playerID = 1
AND games.gametype = 'gameA'
AND (gamestats.stat = 'hits' OR gamestats.stat = 'throws')
```

Here is what it returns:

```
(name, result):  
(hits, 4)  
(throws, 4)  
(hits, 9)  
(throws, 13)
```

It's only a small (very small) step toward my goal.

Comment: Do you want these stats per-game, per-player, or what? It would be best if you showed some sample data and the desired result. Also, instead of showing pseudo-code, show the actual code you tried so we can help you fix it, instead of writing it from scratch for you.

Comment: Oh sorry, yes, it should be per-player and per-gametype. I tried to add some samples above.

Answer (score 2):

You have not mention **Table Name** may be this cause problem

```
SELECT SUM('hits')/SUM('throws') AS GameA_HitsPerThrow From yourTable
WHERE games.gametype = 'gameA';
```

More Details: [Division in Mysql query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12817937/division-in-mysql-query)

Comment: Right, I know that there is a lot missing from the psuedocode. I just need help on the proper structure to get the result of the two sums. I'm sure I'll take some nesting but, like I said, I'm fairly new to SQL.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT g.gameID, g.playerID,
       SUM(CASE WHEN stat = 'hits' THEN result END)/
           SUM(CASE WHEN stat = 'throw' THEN result END) AS GameAHitsPerThrow
FROM games AS g
JOIN gamestats AS s ON g.gameID = s.gameID and g.playerID = s.playerID
WHERE g.gameType = 'gameA'
GROUP BY g.gameID, g.playerID
```

You got duplicate rows because you didn't include `playerID` in the JOIN condition. I'm not really sure why you have separate rows in the `games` table for each player.