# How to get the ratio of two queries

Tags: php, html, sql

I have two different queries:

```
$TotalDLperdaysql=mysqli_query($dbconnect,"SELECT SUM(Duration)/60 AS TotalDLperday FROM dtr_table  WHERE DATE BETWEEN '$datefrom' and '$dateto' AND Labor_Type='OT_DL' OR Labor_Type='Reg_DL'  GROUP BY DATE");

$TotalIDLperdaysql=mysqli_query($dbconnect,"SELECT SUM(Duration)/60 AS TotalIDLperday FROM dtr_table  WHERE DATE BETWEEN '$datefrom' and '$dateto' AND Labor_Type='OT_IDL' OR Labor_Type='Reg_IDL'  GROUP BY DATE");
```

How to write another query to get the ratio of TotalIDLperday/TotalDLperday from the 2 above queries?

Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Division in Mysql query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12817937/division-in-mysql-query)

Answer (score 0):

php sql queries come back as an array.  try the following:

```
$ratio =  $TotalIDLperdaysql[0]/$TotalDLperdaysql[0];
```